# How do you add CFLAGS to cmake to look for dependencies locally?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, openssl

I'm trying to install C++ web framework, `drogon`, which requires following steps to install.

```
cd $WORK_PATH
git clone https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon
cd drogon
git submodule update --init
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make && sudo make install
```

To install locally, I added the following command option,
`cmake --install-prefix=$HOME/local`.

However, the `make` process ended up like this,

```
/bin/ld: ../trantor/libtrantor.a(OpenSSLProvider.cc.o): in function `OpenSSLProvider::processHandshake()':
OpenSSLProvider.cc:(.text._ZN15OpenSSLProvider16processHandshakeEv[_ZN15OpenSSLProvider16processHandshakeEv]+0x504): undefined reference to `SSL_get1_peer_certificate'
/bin/ld: ../trantor/libtrantor.a(openssl.cc.o): in function `trantor::utils::md5(void const*, unsigned long)':
openssl.cc:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/bin/ld: openssl.cc:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_free'
/bin/ld: ../trantor/libtrantor.a(openssl.cc.o): in function `trantor::utils::sha1(void const*, unsigned long)':
openssl.cc:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/bin/ld: openssl.cc:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_free'
/bin/ld: ../trantor/libtrantor.a(openssl.cc.o): in function `trantor::utils::sha256(void const*, unsigned long)':
openssl.cc:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/bin/ld: openssl.cc:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_free'
/bin/ld: ../trantor/libtrantor.a(openssl.cc.o): in function `trantor::utils::sha3(void const*, unsigned long)':
openssl.cc:(.text+0x284): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/bin/ld: openssl.cc:(.text+0x2f0): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_free'
/bin/ld: ../trantor/libtrantor.a(openssl.cc.o): in function `trantor::utils::blake2b(void const*, unsigned long)':
openssl.cc:(.text+0x348): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_fetch'
/bin/ld: openssl.cc:(.text+0x3b4): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/client.dir/build.make:105: examples/client] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:293: examples/CMakeFiles/client.dir/all] Error 2
```

That error is because of the older OpenSSL version the system has, according to `cmake` output.

```
Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "1.1.1f")
```

So I installed newest version (https://www.openssl.org/source/) local (`$HOEM/.local`) as well.

The `OpenSSL` installation was successful but when I tried the `drogon` installation again, I got bounced off at the same step `make` with same error.
Even `cmake` produced the same output as above for the `OpenSSL` path and its version.

My question is how do you make `cmake` look for stuff locally ?
Like other installation process like `./configure`, you can add `CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include` option.
Is there similar method to `cmake` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have a package manager take care of this for you? For example, it should be possible to use vcpkg in manifest mode to install drogon, and list the newer OpenSSL as a dependency. vcpkg can live in your repository as a submodule (that has to be built), and it plugs into cmake. Top it all off with an init script, and you should be good to go.

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html#hints ? what version / commit of drogon did you install? Where did you install your new openssl?

Comment: @sweenish I thought `sudo apt-get upgrade` is the latest versions I could get, nor it didn't occur to me to use other package manager.

Comment: @user  I got the lastest main branch from the github https://github.com/openssl/openssl
And I have it installed under $HOME/.local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it depends on how the CMake projects is searching for its dependencies. If the project uses `find_package(<Package>)`, in many cases you can set a variable `<Package>_ROOT` to point to the installation prefix of the package. In the case of OpenSSL you'll need to use `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` as documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html#hints).

So you need to configure the project with

```
cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=${HOME}/.local ..
```

after deleting the build directory.